# watchdog: BUG: soft lookup - CPU stuck for n s

Tags: ubuntu-22.04, vmware-workstation

I'm currently running ubuntu 22.04 on VMware 17 pro, but it always freezing every 5-10 minutes.
[CPU Stuck](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zOsQd.png)

I already try to upgrade the kernel, make the hardware far below my laptop specification, and make threshold and make panic kernel to 0 with command:
echo "kernel.watchdog_thresh=300" >> /etc/sysctl.conf sysctl --system
echo "kernel.softlockup_panic=0" >> /etc/sysctl.conf sysctl --system

but it keep freezing everytime. Does anybody know how to fix this problem?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.